# Употребление слова "вживую"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли так составить предложение: "Посмотрите шкафы вживую."

Answer (score 1):

Можно сказать так: посмотрите, как выглядят шкафы  вживую.

Обычно пишут: вы можете посмотреть,  как выглядит реальная мебель или мебель в реальности.

Но разговорное слово "вживую", которое обычно относится к лицам, по отношению к мебели тоже употребляют, например: "Предлагаем посетить наши выставочные залы в Москве и посмотреть модели мебели из разных коллекций вживую". Иногда слово заключают в кавычки, обозначая условность употребления.

ВЖИВУЮ, нареч. Разг. 1. Лично, непосредственно (не в записи, без фонограммы). Услышать рок-ансамбль в. Петь в. (о певце). 2. Наглядно, своими глазами. Увидеть в. знаменитого футболиста.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, можно. Примеры показывают, что наречие "вживую" стало употребляться и применительно к неодушевленным предметам.

*Очень понравился художник! Хотелось бы на работы посмотреть вживую.* [Лада Фокс, nick] (Из Нацкопруса)

*Вживую ёлка выглядела намного красивее, чем на фотографии*. «Форум» (Из [Викисловаря](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E))